# How to most efficiently compare date components in Amazon Athena?

Tags: sql, performance, date, amazon-athena

I have two near identical tables with following schema, containing an account number, value, and date split into 3 values, but with a formatting difference. There can many rows per account/day. I am using Amazon Athena.

```
CREATE TABLE tableA (
accnt_num string,   --ex: 8923747897423
value1 int,      
partition_0 string, --ex: 2021
partition_1 string, --ex: 01
partition_2 string, --ex: 07
);

CREATE TABLE tableB (
accnt_num string,   --ex: 8923747897423
value2 int,
partition_0 string, --ex: 2021
partition_1 string, --ex: 1
partition_2 string, --ex: 7
);
```

I want to join the table on the partitions being the same (yes the account numbers matching would also be a condition of the join, but that is easy as they are in same format/data type and so is not focus of question). What is the fastest way to do so, assuming >10,000,000 rows?

```
SELECT * FROM tableA a 
JOIN tableB b
on cast(a.partition_2 as int) = cast(b.partition_2 as int) 
...
```

or

any other variety of string manipulation (adding the 0 for example if there is no 0 in the first position, trimming the 0 if it exists in the first position on the other table, etc...)

or

combining them together first, casting as a date, and then comparing to the other table?

I would like it to be as efficiently as possible.

Comment: There is no fast way.  Fix the data so the types are the same in the corresponding columns.

Comment: I have no access to this and cannot change it

Comment: 10 Million records right ? Well there's not likely 10Million different dates ... so I'd hash the partitions ... then create a lookup table mapping each hash into a nicely formatted date. (yes you'd generate a lookup table for each date from some date dimension -> along with each variant of hash that can map to the date)

Comment: @AdrianWhite missed a part of it lol sorry. Edited

Comment: You didn't indicate the data type of this fields.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I have edited the question to provide data types.

Comment: @jarlh I have edited the question to reflect this, but I am using Amazon Athena

Comment: I suggest you read this: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/top-10-performance-tuning-tips-for-amazon-athena/ I didn't see anything about whether joining three columns is better or worse than joining one calculated column. In a normal relational DB it is usuallly better to avoid applying functions to columns. I suspect this may the same for a hive based system. In short I don't see any reason thay you shouldn't just join the three columns seperately without and calc applied.

Comment: In traditional RDBMS. you should avoid casting data to a different data type if you don't have (i.e. they are all the same datatype). I assume this would be the same. There is unlikely to be any advantage comparing int > int vs string > string, and there will be a performance hit for having to transform strings to int. Unless this is a data cleansing exercise (i.e. removing leading zeros)

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid are you saying that removing the leading 0  wouldn't suffer a performance hit that the casting delivers? How about concatenating it in it for the other value?

Comment: Oops I should have read your question properly. In that case it probably is a good idea to cast both sides. But I'm not an expert in this, this is idle conjecture at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt type conversion is going to make much difference, other things will have a bigger impact on the performance.

In a distributed engine like Athena, network overhead is going to dominate the running time of queries. CPU bound processing is going to be more than an order or magnitude less important.

The general recommendation to optimize joins in Athena is to list the tables in order of size, biggest first. If one of your tables is smaller, making sure it isn't the first table will make a big difference.

After that you must make sure that Athena is able to prune partitions properly. Use `EXPLAIN` and the `totalBytesScanned` statistic to make sure that Athena isn't reading too much data (e.g. I don't know if Athena is smart enough to correctly prune partitions on both tables in `SELECT * FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON (t1.partition0 = t2.partition0) WHERE t1.partition0 = 'xyz'`, you might for example need to add `AND t2.partition0 = 'xyz'`).

Once you are sure that you have optimized away as much network overhead as possible you can simply run queries with casts and without casts and see if there is any measurable difference, but I doubt you will be able to observe any.